# LXDE doesn't start - fonts missing?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, lxde, xhost

So I have my Raspberry Pi (B+), and want to run LXDE on it. Should be installed. So I run startx, and i get a black screen with a dash in the top left corner. Weird. XINIT tells me XTERM isn't installed, so I installed it. But I didnt get any farther, I now get font errors.

Anyone able to help out?

My log file:

```
[  1331.843]
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
[  1331.853] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1331.856] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-2-mx5 armv7l Debian
[  1331.862] Current Operating System: Linux codica 3.18.8+ #2 PREEMPT Mon Mar $
[  1331.863] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bc$
[  1331.893] Build Date: 11 February 2015  09:31:17PM
[  1331.899] xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u6 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org$
[  1331.903] Current version of pixman: 0.33.1
[  1331.909]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1331.909] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1331.935] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri May  1 11:10:16 20$
[  1331.940] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1331.946] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1331.949] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1331.949] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1331.949] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1331.949] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1331.952] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1331.953] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1331.953] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1331.953] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" does not exist.
[  1331.954]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1331.954] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1331.954]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1331.954] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  1331.954]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1331.955] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1331.955]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1331.955] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1331.955]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1331.956] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1331.956]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1331.956] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueTy$
[  1331.957]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1331.957] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[  1331.957] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1331.957] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input device$
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevi$
[  1331.957] (II) Loader magic: 0xb6feccf0
[  1331.958] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1331.958]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1331.958]    X.Org Video Driver: 12.1
[  1331.958]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[  1331.958]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[  1331.959] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[  1331.963] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[  1331.968] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1331.968]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1331.968]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1331.969]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1331.969] (II) Loading extension SELinux
[  1331.969] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  1331.969] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  1331.970] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[  1331.970] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[  1331.970] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[  1331.970] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  1331.971] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[  1331.971] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[  1331.974] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[  1331.976] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1331.976]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1331.976]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1331.976]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1331.977] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  1331.977] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1331.979] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1331.982] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1331.982]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1331.982]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1331.983] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  1331.983] (II) Loading extension GLX
[  1331.984] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[  1331.986] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[  1331.988] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1331.988]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.13.0
[  1331.989]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  1331.989]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1331.989] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[  1331.989] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[  1331.992] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[  1331.995] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1331.995]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1331.995]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1331.995] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[  1331.996] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  1331.998] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[  1332.001] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1332.001]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.2.0
[  1332.002]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  1332.002] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[  1332.002] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1332.003] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1332.003] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1332.004] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1332.006] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1332.006]    compiled for 1.12.1, module version = 0.4.2
[  1332.006]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[  1332.007] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  1332.007] (--) using VT number 7

[  1332.011] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  1332.011] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1332.011] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1332.013] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1332.014] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1332.014]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 0.0.2
[  1332.014]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
[  1332.015] (II) FBDEV(0): using default device
[  1332.015] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  1332.016] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen secti$
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 16/16
[  1332.016] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 16, (==) framebuffer bpp 16
[  1332.016] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 565
[  1332.016] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1332.017] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  1332.017] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: BCM2708 FB (video memory: 533kB)
[  1332.017] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[  1332.017] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[  1332.017] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 656x416 (pitch 656)
[  1332.018] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current"
[  1332.018] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  1332.018] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  1332.018] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  1332.020] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  1332.022] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1332.023]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  1332.023]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1332.023] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[  1332.023] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[  1332.024] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[  1332.025] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[  1332.027] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1332.027]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.1.0
[  1332.028]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1332.031] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store disabled
[  1332.033] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[  1332.033] (==) RandR enabled
[  1332.033] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[  1332.033] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[  1332.034] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[  1332.034] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[  1332.034] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[  1332.034] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  1332.034] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[  1332.035] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[  1332.035] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[  1332.035] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[  1332.035] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[  1332.035] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[  1332.036] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[  1332.036] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[  1332.036] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[  1332.036] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[  1332.037] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  1332.149] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  1332.150] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI capable
[  1332.191] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  1332.191] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[  1332.559] (II) config/udev: Adding input device   Mini Keyboard (/dev/input/$
[  1332.559] (**)   Mini Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1332.559] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[  1332.561] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[  1332.562] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1332.563]    compiled for 1.12.1, module version = 2.7.0
[  1332.563]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1332.563]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
[  1332.563] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for '  Mini Keyboard'
[  1332.563] (**)   Mini Keyboard: always reports core events
[  1332.564] (**) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[  1332.564] (--) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Vendor 0x1997 Product 0x2433
[  1332.565] (--) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Found keys
[  1332.565] (II) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[  1332.565] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/$
[  1332.565] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "  Mini Keyboard" (type:$
[  1332.565] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1332.566] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc101"
[  1332.566] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1332.566] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:ralt_alt,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[  1332.846] (II) config/udev: Adding input device   Mini Keyboard (/dev/input/$
[  1332.846] (**)   Mini Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[  1332.847] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for '  Mini Keyboard'
[  1332.847] (**)   Mini Keyboard: always reports core events
[  1332.847] (**) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[  1332.848] (--) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Vendor 0x1997 Product 0x2433
[  1332.848] (--) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Found 9 mouse buttons
[  1332.848] (--) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Found scroll wheel(s)
[  1332.848] (--) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Found relative axes
[  1332.848] (--) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Found x and y relative axes
[  1332.848] (--) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Found absolute axes
[  1332.849] (II) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[  1332.849] (--) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Found keys
[  1332.849] (II) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Configuring as mouse
[  1332.849] (II) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[  1332.849] (II) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Adding scrollwheel support
[  1332.850] (**) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[  1332.850] (**) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelIn$
[  1332.851] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/$
[  1332.851] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "  Mini Keyboard" (type:$
[  1332.851] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1332.851] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc101"
[  1332.852] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1332.852] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:ralt_alt,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[  1332.854] (II) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: initialized for relative axes.
[  1332.854] (WW) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: ignoring absolute axes.
[  1332.856] (**)   Mini Keyboard: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  1332.856] (**)   Mini Keyboard: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[  1332.857] (**)   Mini Keyboard: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1332.857] (**)   Mini Keyboard: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1332.861] (II) config/udev: Adding input device   Mini Keyboard (/dev/input/$
[  1332.861] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1332.861] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1332.865] (II) config/udev: Adding input device stmpe-ts (/dev/input/event2)
[  1332.865] (**) stmpe-ts: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
[  1332.865] (**) stmpe-ts: Applying InputClass "calibration"
[  1332.865] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'stmpe-ts'
[  1332.866] (**) stmpe-ts: always reports core events
[  1332.866] (**) evdev: stmpe-ts: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[  1332.866] (--) evdev: stmpe-ts: Vendor 0 Product 0
[  1332.867] (--) evdev: stmpe-ts: Found absolute axes
[  1332.867] (--) evdev: stmpe-ts: Found x and y absolute axes
[  1332.867] (--) evdev: stmpe-ts: Found absolute touchscreen
[  1332.867] (**) Option "SwapAxes" "1"
[  1332.867] (II) evdev: stmpe-ts: Configuring as touchscreen
[  1332.868] (**) evdev: stmpe-ts: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[  1332.868] (**) evdev: stmpe-ts: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: $
[  1332.868] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/soc/20204000.spi/spi_$
[  1332.869] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "stmpe-ts" (type: TOUCHS$
[  1332.869] (II) evdev: stmpe-ts: initialized for absolute axes.
[  1332.871] (**) stmpe-ts: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  1332.871] (**) stmpe-ts: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[  1332.872] (**) stmpe-ts: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1332.872] (**) stmpe-ts: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1332.874] (II) config/udev: Adding input device stmpe-ts (/dev/input/mouse1)
[  1332.875] (**) stmpe-ts: Applying InputClass "calibration"
[  1332.875] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1332.875] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1349.930] (II) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Close
[  1349.931] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  1349.981] (II) evdev:   Mini Keyboard: Close
[  1349.981] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  1350.010] (II) evdev: stmpe-ts: Close
[  1350.011] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  1350.033] Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```